# Handle languages in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to solve the next problem:

1) When entering the url without language, use English language as default
example:

> http//localhost/plants/ or http//localhost/plants

or

> http//localhost/plants/shop/accessories

2) When entering the url with language, pass that parameter as the language to use
example:

> http//localhost/plants/es/shop/accessories

or

> http//localhost/plants/es/ or http//localhost/plants/es

So far I have tried:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(en|es)/(.*)$ index.php?url=$2&lang=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1&lang=en [L,QSA]
```

If I comment the first RewriteRule and enter any url it works fine but always using the en language.

If I comment the second RewriteRule and I use a url with the language:

> http//localhost/plants/es/

or

> http//localhost/plants/es/shop/accessories

It works fine, but it doesn't set the default language to English when is not given.

Any idea why it doesn't work when I leave the two rules?

Thanks

Ps: I have removed the : after http

Comment: it does not work because the last one overrides the previous one.

Change the order so first it wikll set as "en" and then if there is "en|es" it will set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `plants` is your document root, you should be able to use this rule.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(en|es)
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?url=$1&lang=en [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(en|es)/?(.*)/?$ index.php?url=$2&lang=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Let me know how it works for you.

Comment: Yeah It works perfectly except when I write the url: `http://localhost/plants/en` without the last slash, then is not working. What modification should I do to be working when not entering the last slash after the language?
Thanks man!

Comment: @NicolásGonzález Ok I updated the answer to make the / optional in the rewrite rule. Clear your browser cache and see if this fixes your problem.

Comment: Awesome! Works perfectly, thanks for helping! I hate this evil .htaccess language

Answer (score 1):

Put the following htaccess file inside the `/plants` directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /plants

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/plants/e[ns](/|$) [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !lang=e[ns] [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /plants/en/$0 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(e[ns])/(.*)$ index.php?url=$2&lang=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

---

If the above still doesn't work, update your own approach to something like:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(en|es)/(.*)$ index.php?url=$2&lang=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1&lang=en [L,QSA]
```

Comment: that redirects to: http://localhost/plants/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/shop/accessories

Comment: @NicolásGonzález There was a typing mistake. Should work now ^. Please check

Comment: still wrong... it redirects to:
http://localhost/plants/en/index.php?url=index.php&lang=en&url=index.php&lang=en&url=index.php&lang=en&url=index.php&lang=en&url=index.php&lang=en&url=index.php&lang=en&url=index.php&lang=en&url=index.php&lang=en&url=index.php&lang=en&url=index.php&lang=en&url=index.php&lang=en&url=index.php&lang=en&url=index.php&lang=en&url=index.php&lang=en&url=index.php&lang=en&url=index.php&lang=en&url=index.php&lang=en&url=index.php&lang=en&url=account/sign&lang=en

Comment: it works this way:

`RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(en|es)/(.*)$ index.php?url=$2&lang=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(en|es)(.*)$ index.php?url=$2&lang=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1&lang=en [L,QSA]`

But there is a better way for sure

Comment: @NicolásGonzález updated the reply again. I keep mixing `REQUEST_URI` and `THE_REQUEST` variables.

Comment: @hjpotter92 haha, identical answer. I guess I was creating it when you were updating

Comment: haha yeah, well at least we have found a solution :)

Thanks man for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution doing this:

> RewriteEngine On
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
>
> RewriteRule ^(en|es)/(.*)$ index.php?url=$2&lang=$1 [L,QSA]
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
>
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1&lang=en [L,QSA]

How can I improve this? It feels wrong I have to write twto time the same Cond